# allow users in a specific group to change posts UserPassesTestMixin

Tags: python, django, mixins

I have a user and a group called Manager. How do I allow a user in the Manager group to change a post that's not theirs?

Here's my code so far

```
class UserAccessMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self, user):
        issue = self.get_object()
        mod = user.get_object()

        if self.request.user == issue.author:
            return True
        elif user.object.user == mod.groups.filter(name='Manager').exists():
            return True
        return False
```

And my models

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    MARK_AS = ((True, 'Open'), (False, 'Closed'))

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    mark_as = models.BooleanField(choices=MARK_AS, default=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('issue-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I get the error `UserAccessMixin.test_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'`

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obtain the user with `self.request.user`, so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class UserAccessMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    
    #       no user 🖟
    def test_func(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return user.groups.filter(name='Manager').exists() or self.get_object().author == user
```

Comment: Doing this just broke the entire app, if I try to change it back, and use all the features, it's now saying that  ```'Issue' object has no attribute 'user'``` even though I deleted the code

Comment: @mdaw11: it looks like you somewhere use `.user`, for an `Issue` object, whereas it should be `.author`. You should look at the traceback to find out where.

Comment: I literally just changed it back to how it was before and its still not working

Comment: @mdaw11: well then it is either a `.pyc` file (binary by-product of the compiler), or there is some code that does not fully work. You should look at the traceback.